# Changing margin value on time interval

Tags: android, image, layout, parameters, timer

Below is a snippet of the code I have written out.  I have a large scrollable image in the background and a smaller image in the foreground.  The layout is working fine for me, statically. What I want to do is, after an interval of 5 seconds, randomize a new location for the foreground image by changing the topMargin and leftMargin.  I know that a pseudo-random number generator can be used to change the value.  But, I'm not sure how to declare that I want the "params.topMargin" and "params.leftMargin" values to change or how to make that happen on a timer.

```
            mImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.Image1);

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new
            LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.topMargin = 1200;
    params.leftMargin = 45;

    mImage.setLayoutParams(params);
```

For constraint reasons, I know that range of value the random number generator can be pre-defined, and I will need to do that also.

If anyone could help to point me in the right direction, that would be wonderful :D

Edit:  I'm fairly certain I need to use a timer, an intent, and getRandom() in conjunction with one-another.  I'm just not quite certain how to put them all together correctly.

Comment: This gives you a integer between 1 and N: `(int)(Math.random()*N + 1);`

Comment: But how to you tell the random function to change the values of params.topMargin and .leftMargin, respectively?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on your onCreate method:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {

        mImage = (ImageView)YourActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.Image1);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new
            LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        params.topMargin = (int)(Math.random()*500 + 1); //500 is the max margin, you can change it
        params.leftMargin = (int)(Math.random()*500 + 1); //500 is the max margin, you can change it

        mImage.setLayoutParams(params);

        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000); //1000 is the interval in milliseconds
    }
};
r.run();
```

Comment: This is working... sort of.  Before, with the above code, the foreground image was the one that was moving.  Now, with your correction, the background image is moving.  I can't tell what has changed in order to fix it...

Comment: Nevermind that, i mixed up the ids for the background and foreground images when i pasted your code.  Perfect answer!  Thank you so much for the help!